# Intel-inde for android camera capture/live streaming problems

Tags: android, video-streaming, surfaceview, glsurfaceview, intelinde

I am playing around with Intel-inde and am running into trouble with CameraCapture and live streaming.

I've loaded the external JARs and the 4 armeabi .so files into my project.  I've made a basic program basically copying the CameraStreamerActivity.java and have this code:

```
camera = createCamera();
capture = new CameraCapture(new AndroidMediaObjectFactory(getApplicationContext()), progressListener);
capture.createPreview(findViewById(R.id.surfaceView), camera);
```

I am getting these errors:

10-08 18:29:42.459: I/dalvikvm(9062): Could not find method android.opengl.EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext, referenced from method com.intel.inde.mp.android.AndroidMediaObjectFactory.getCurrentEglContext

10-08 18:29:42.459: W/dalvikvm(9062): VFY: unable to resolve static method 526: Landroid/opengl/EGL14;.eglGetCurrentContext ()Landroid/opengl/EGLContext;

Would appreciate some help as to what is causing this.  Thank you.

Comment: What device, and what version of Android, are you using?

Comment: I'm using a galaxy S2 and Android 4.2  You're right, only 4.3+ is supported by this project.  Do you know if there's any way to get this functionality working in 4.2?

Comment: Things got a lot easier and more stable in 4.3, which is why Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) also requires 4.3.  In older releases it's very difficult to get good performance without using non-public native APIs... you could send the camera output to YUV ByteBuffers and work from that, but you'll be operating at a few frames per second while taxing the device heavily.  The Surface input to MediaCodec introduced in 4.3 makes many interesting things possible.

Comment: Hi nyc0202034, did you manage to make it working?

Comment: Hi Marlon, I ended up converting my project to 4.3 :)